# mypy does not recognize assert and shows an error

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

Considering the following code in x.py

```
from typing import Dict, List, Union


def _func2(do_something: bool) -> Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]]]:
    dict1: Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]] = dict()
    dict2: Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]] = dict()
    dict3: Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]] = dict()
    if (do_something):
        dict1['key1'] = 'string1'
        if ('key1' not in dict2.keys()):
            dict2['key1'] = list()
        assert(isinstance(dict2['key1'], list))
        dict2['key1'].append('otherstring')
    return {'outer_key_1': dict1, 'outer_key_2': dict2, 'outer_key_3': dict3}


def _func1(do_something: bool) -> Dict[str, Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]]]:
    dict1: Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]] = dict()
    dict2: Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]] = dict()
    dict3: Dict[str, Union[str, List[str]]] = dict()
    keys: List[str] = ['key1']
    if (do_something):
        dict1['key1'] = 'string1'
        if (keys[0] not in dict2.keys()):
            dict2[keys[0]] = list()
        assert(isinstance(dict2[keys[0]], list))
        dict2[keys[0]].append('otherstring')
    return {'outer_key_1': dict1, 'outer_key_2': dict2, 'outer_key_3': dict3}
```

the command `mypy --strict --show-error-codes x.py` shows

```
x.py:27: error: Item "str" of "Union[str, List[str]]" has no attribute "append"  [union-attr]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

**Note**: The only difference between _func2 and _func1 is, that in _func1 the key is part of a list of strings, not directly a string.

The code is functional when run - and of course if the functions are called - but how can I satisfy mypy if I need to use _func1 (the list in the code sample is static, in real life it's not)?

Comment: You could probably get around this by setting `x = dict[keys[0]]; assert isinstance(x, list); x.append(...)` - it's clunky though, so I'll just leave it as a comment and hopefully someone can answer with something more idiomatic / elegant.

Comment: Can you cut down this code a bit, please? Even after looking at this for a while, I am not sure which parts are relevant and where MyPy (supposedly) trips. Do I see it correctly that the change boils down to using a *literal* ``'key1'`` versus a *dynamic* ``keys[0]``? Are the three dicts relevant, or would one suffice?

Comment: Hi @MisterMiyagi, did you read my "note"? I think this explains it quite well, doesn't it? If you copied the code to a python file and ran mypy with exactly the command I included you would see where line 27 is... I really don't see how I could make this much easier to follow, sorry.

Comment: You can definitely remove ``dict1``, ``dict3`` and ``do_something``. The ``if (... not in dict2.keys()):`` seems redundant as well – you can directly initialise ``dict2`` to ``{'key1': []}``. You can also drop the non-idiomatic parentheses for all boolean checks, though only the ``assert`` would remain after the previous cleanup. [That cuts the function size easily in half](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=b19ef7e493b84a90d492d51e85467cc6).

Answer (score 0):

I also opened a ticket for mypy: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11732
The ticket got closed with a link to https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11534 which explains that this will not be implemented - and as a solution provides an example like mentioned by hyper-neutrino in the comment.

Comment: Can you please include the relevant information in the answer itself? It's hard enough to know from the question what "this" is, and the solution in both the linked issue and unlinked comment may be unreachable in the future.

Comment: "type narrowing of subscript expressions isn't supported when the subscript expression is dynamic, it is supported when the subscript expression is a string or numeric literal value. Type narrowing for dynamic subscript expressions is very difficult to implement because it requires the type checker to ensure that the value of the expression found within the type guard test evaluates the same value as the expression found within the guarded block" from [https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11534](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/11534)